# Go http request redirect

Tags: http, go, redirect, request

I am writing an API whichs has to redirect incoming requests to another service, the response must be forwarded to the original requester.

I figured a simple function like below should do the trick, but I was wrong.

I receive the data from my redirected response, however when I send it back to the initial request I receive this response without any data `Could not get response. Error: socket hang up`

If I try to execute the very same request using postman straight to the redirect URL it works perfectly fine.

```golang
func initialAssetsHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    resp, err := http.Post(conf.redirectURL, "application/json", bytes.NewReader(body))
    if err != nil {
        log.Error(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    buf.ReadFrom(resp.Body)
    log.Info(string(buf.Bytes()))

    var data json.RawMessage
    if err = json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&data); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    helper.SendJsonRaw(w, 200, data)
}
```

Here is the SendJsonRaw function:

```golang
func SendJsonRaw(w http.ResponseWriter, status int, r json.RawMessage) error {
    w.Header().Set(HeaderContentType, MimeApplicationJSON)
    w.WriteHeader(status)
    _, err := w.Write(r)
    return err
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `r.Body` is read by the json decoder up to `EOF`, then when you pass it to the redirect request it looks *empty* to the http.Client and therefore it sends no body. You need to retain the content of the body.

For example you can do the following:

```golang
func initialAssetsHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    var initialAssets TagAssets
    if err := json.Unmarshal(&initialAssets, body); err != nil {
        if !strings.Contains(err.Error(), "json: invalid use of ,string struct tag, trying to unmarshal") {
            helper.SendJsonError(w, http.StatusBadRequest, err)
            return
        }
    }

    resp, err := http.Post(conf.redirectURL, "application/json", bytes.NewReader(body))
    if err != nil {
        log.Error(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    log.Info(resp)

    var data json.RawMessage
    if err := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&data); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    helper.SendJsonOk(w, data)
}
```

Comment: Hi @mkopriva, that worked, I am receiving the response I needed from the  other service, however now when I send it back to my initial request from postman I do not receive it. Why might this be?

Comment: @Marius if I understand your problem correctly the issue is with the `SendJsonOk` function and the fact that you're passing `resp` directly as the second argument. I'll edit the answer to add a fix for that.

Comment: @Marius I've updated the example code, try it out and let me know if it works now. Note also that I've added `defer resp.Body.Close()`, this is important, if you don't close response bodies you'll leak memory.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but now for some reason the original request does not get my response. I logged the response body from the redirected request and I receive the data I needed. however when I write the response to the initial request. I receive `Could not get response. Error: socket hang up` I tried a lot of code variations, but for some reason my Postman request does not get the needed response.

Comment: @Marius please update the question by adding the new handler code that you're running, and do not leave out any details, they may be important. Also add a comment to the line of code that is causing the error so that I know exactly where it's coming from.

Comment: @Marius you're doing the same mistake with `resp.Body` as you did in your original question with `r.Body`, you're reading the body with `buf.ReadFrom` up to `EOF`, and then you're trying to re-read it with `json.NewDecoder().Decode`... You simply can't do that. Remove the whole `buf` block of code, and if you want to print the contents of the body, print them after you decode them into the `data json.RawMessage` variable, like so: `log.Info(string(data))`.

Comment: @Marius it is also better generally to use `json.NewEncoder().Encode` to *write* json to the response, something like this should work: https://play.golang.org/p/bTiQsyvrC8H

Comment: I tried it, but I receive the same response. For some reason it seems like the initial request ignores the response. I do not understand why. Its as if the responseWriter does not respond to the initial request even tho my postman request only closes when my API sends out the response to the initial request..

Comment: @Marius the code works just fine, see: https://imgur.com/ylUMTo3. If you have an issue with Postman, the problem may be in how you use Postman, or the problem may be with the server that's serving `conf.redirectURL`, the Go code I've provided is valid and works.